# How do I assert this properly?

Tags: truffle-contract, truffle-test

Say I want to make a test for this sample contract:

```
// assume we import OpenZeppelin's Ownable

contract Metaverse extends Ownable, ... {
    ...
    // Assume this is just to experiment and learn.
    // Then I can question myself how useful is to
    // actually do this, and why.
    function renounceOwnership() public override onlyOwner {
        revert("I explicitly disabled this method");
    }
    ...
}
```

And, using [trufflesuite](http://trufflesuite.com) I want to make a test for when the method reverts:

```
const Metaverse = artifacts.require("Metaverse");

contract("Metaverse", function (accounts) {
  const deployer = accounts[0];
  const newOwner = accounts[1];

  it("respects the safe-ownership appropriately", async function () {
    let metaverse = await Metaverse.deployed();

    try
    {
      metaverse.renounceOwnership({from: deployer});
      assert.fail("Ownership should not be rejected");
    }
    catch(e) { /* Ok :) - It will be an AssertionError */ }
  });
});
```

So far, this WORKS, but I want to make it cleaner. So I divide my question in two:

1. Is there a STANDARD AND CLEANER/BETTER way to assert when a method reverts?
2. If not: How do I test that e is of type AssertionError? Where do I import that assertion error from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Waffle with the `revertedWith` Chai Matcher: https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html#revert-with-message

An example for this can be seen here: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/test/libraries/MultiSend.spec.ts#L51